# IE stores data in cache, changes not reflecting in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

IE stored the data in cache and even if there are changes, its not reflecting onclick. But when I open the developer mode and try to access the same, then it works perfectly. In all other browsers its fine.

Other weird thing its working properly in local setup, it has issue in production. I have already use the meta tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

But no hope. Can any one please help?

Here is my jQuery:

```
        function showSubjectItems(){

            var dis = $("#myTopic").css('display');

            if(dis == 'none'){

                $("#myTopic").css({display: 'block'}).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 100, function(){

                    pleasewait();

                    $("#myTopic").empty().load("mygroupmessagesItem.xhtml"); 

                }); 


            }else{

                $("#myTopic").css({display: 'none'}).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 100, function(){

                    $("#myTopic").empty();

                });

            }

        }
```

Comment: Could we see the actual code which is generating the error you're describing? If not the code, then a [mcve].

Comment: What is being cached exactly?

Comment: I have a jQuery function to retrive new list of folders from database. The div will fetch only on click. In IE even if I create new folders, its not showing in my div.

Comment: maybe this can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168963/stop-jquery-load-response-from-being-cached

Comment: I put this  $.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
}); at the top of my main.js script, but no hope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code inside your scripts to prevent caching of ajax calls

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

If this doesn't work then code below will definitely work.

```
$("#myTopic").empty().load("mygroupmessagesItem.xhtml?random="+Math.random());
```

appending a random value as parameter to URL will not prevent result from loading from cache, give it a try. Upvote if it helps.

Comment: Do I need to give this in every click? I put in main.js file  but it did't worked for me.