# HTML files don't refresh unless they are accessed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a setup in which I make AJAX calls to load the html files containing to be displayed data. Let's say the main page is index.html and I have two other pages: pages/1.html and pages/2.html. In index.html either 1 or 2 is set as content. My browser however caches both 1 and 2 and when I change either of them and reload the page it won't display the changes I've made because I didn't actually refresh 1.html or 2.html. How can I make it so that this is not an issue?

Comment: Can we see your code?

Answer (score 0):

I did look for answers however didn't find one so I decided to make a question out of it. I just found an answer so I'll post it here:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
});
```

Credits to: [John Millikin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/168977/2452215)