# Preventing caching image from jQuery load

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I make a page, I'm stucking in caching problem. Here is my simplified code.

**[HTML]**

```
<body>
    <div>here parent contents</div>
    <input id="btn1" class="btn" data-val="1" type="button" />
    <input id="btn2" class="btn" data-val="2" type="button" />
    <input id="btn3" class="btn" data-val="3" type="button" />
    <div id="childContents"></div>
</body>
```

**[javascript]**

```
$(".btn").click(function (e) {
    $("#childContents").load("url?val=" + e.getAttribute("data-val"),
    function () {
        success call back function
    });
});
```

And the point is that :

**[Child Html]**

```
<!-- the image change depanding on some condition -->
<div style="background-image: url('imgUrl')">
    contents
</div>
```

Whenever I click button and re`load` the child view, I hope the image, which child view has, change. 
But since the cached image, the child's image does not change. How can I do for it?

I want to solve it with javascript, since sometimes the jquery version become a big problem and I always consider the version of it. So I want to make my code of small dependance on jQuery. (eg. jquery’s async ajax’s option and so on is not working lower version of IE)

Comment: I think the cache not of jquery, maybe your backend server caching your images using apache, nginx or maybe Varnish.

Comment: @Adam might be right, jquery has no cache for images, in order to implement such a cache you would need some sort of preload... so this might be cache by server side, you can use a get with a timestamp at the end probably

Comment: add a random value in your url (get the current time),  it is caused by the webbrowser cache, you can using wireshark to check if the new request is send out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop jQuery .load response from being cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168963/stop-jquery-load-response-from-being-cached)

Comment: The server has no cache and I’m trying to solve it in front. Thnak you all !! :)

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden Also it is very helpful answer I could’nt find ! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the current time as a cache breaker.

```
$(".btn").click(function (e) {
    $("#childContents").load("url?val=" + e.getAttribute("data-val"),
    function () {
        //get time since 1970 in milliseonds
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.UTC();
        //append a cache breaker
        var imgUrl = "background.jpg" + "?t=" + n;
        //set the img url
        $('#backgrounddiv').css('background-image', 'url("'+imgUrl+'")');

    });
});


<div id="backgrounddiv" style="background-image: url('background.jpg')">
    contents
</div>
```