# getJSON not really calling php page

Tags: php, ajax

Anyone can give me a hint why this getJSON not really calling the PHP page. I am trying to understand some existing code which uses getJSON.

"**getfolders.php**" page would write a message to a log first as the first step.

My javascript is as below:

```
$.getJSON('api/getfolders.php', {});
//window.location="api/getfolders.php";
```

If I use getJSON, it is only working sort of first time entering this javascript, if I click `CTRL+F5`, it doesn't trigger the "getfolders.php" multiple times.

However if comment out getJSON and use window.location instead, every CTRL+F5 will trigger the "getfolders.php" for every time.

Is it some behavior in ajax causing this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Could you add whole script? How is your event listener is registered to specific element? Maybe some dynamically loaded HTML elements don't have assigned event properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GET requests are cached by the browser.
To check it change a request for following 
`'api/getfolders.php' + Date.now()`
but it is not good way.

[Look at discussion of this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168963/stop-jquery-load-response-from-being-cached)

Perhaps you should use $ .post () function.

Comment: The browser caches the GET requests. You really should use POST to prevent this. Adding a timestamp or a random value which is not cached helps overriding the cache in case of GET (because the URL is different each time), but at the end the browser stores "crap".